# is it recommended to change all old 302 redirections to 301?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, 302-redirect

I have a client which has 302 redirected all the http pages to https pages 4 years ago.
Now is it recommended to change all the 302 redirections to 301 or should I keep them the same?
Also they have 302 redirected http://example.com website to https://www.example.com and then 301 redirect https://www.example.com version to https://example.com and making a redirection chain.
What is the best practice for SEO in this case?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance:)

Comment: Nothing wrong with redirect chains as long as they are not excessive, you're concerned about a non-problem. 99.999% of your visitors will use the link on Google, with no redirects.

Comment: @SimonHayter Redirect chains are OK, but the one in the question is a bit of a silly one and should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Https redirects

In the [Google official guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en&ref_topic=6001951), they recommend using `301 redirect` for https redirections, so you need to change 302 for 301.

> Redirect your users and search engines to the HTTPS page or resource with server-side 301 HTTP redirects.

### Multiple redirects

Try to avoid unnecessary redirects cause it [slows down your page load speed](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/redirects). Here you have an optimized Apache [.htaccess configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/2369981).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also set your preferred domain access in [Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en).

Comment: "avoid unnecessary redirects" - ironically, these directives result in a double redirect when requesting `http://www.example.com`. However, that isn't necessarily a bad thing (and is actually required if later configuring HSTS).